# CoucbDB Ubuntu 14 Azure Socket Connection Timeout error

Tags: linux, azure, connection, couchdb, ubuntu-14.04

I have couchdb running on a Linux Ubuntu 14.04 VM and a .net Web application running under Azure Web Apps. Under our ELMAH logging for the web application I keep getting intermittent errors:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly    respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond [ipaddress]:5984
```

I've checked the CouchDB logs and there isn't a record of those requests so I don't believe it's hitting the CouchDB server, I can confirm this by looking at the web server logs on Azure and see the Error 500 response. I've also tried a tcpdump however with little success (another issue logging tcpdump to a separate disk keeps failing due to access denied)

We've previously ran CouchDB on a Windows VM with no issues so I wonder if the issue relates to the OS connection settings for tcp and timeouts

Anyone have any suggestions as to where to look or what immediately jumps to mind?

Comment: Hi. Please, comments your solution.